# Capturar Exception de Stripe en Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, excepciones, depuración, stripe

## Incidencia

Estuve usando mis variables de testing (prueba) que Stripe provee, pero lugar de usar una targeta de prueba usé una real, hacer esto generó una excepcion: **No debo de usar tarjetas live(reales) en modo test(prueba)**, pero el problema es que Laravel no capturá la Excepcion, asi que no puedo manejarlo, usé herramientas para depurar que son las siguientes:

- [Clockwork](https://github.com/itsgoingd/clockwork)
- [Laravel DebugBar](https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-debugbar)
- [Laravel Telescope](https://github.com/laravel/telescope)

Unicamente me di cuenta en el log de `storage/logs/laravel.log`, pero yo deseo manejar la excepcion y retornar `{ errors: { card: [ 'invalid card' ] } }` **¿ quien mas le pasó ? ¿ como capturo el error ?**

## Algunos datos:

- Laravel 6.x
- Stripe 7.4 (php)

Answer (score 0):

La solucion a este problema problema era mas sencillo de lo que parece, incluso el propio editor de codigo me estaba advirtiendo, hace poco hice upgrade de Laravel 5.7 a 6.x, esto trajo muchos cambios en las versiones de las dependencias, incluida la version de Stripe, de v6.43 -> v7.43, por lo que en el try catch de mi codigo se usa Stripe\Error\Card (que es una excepcion personalidad de Stripe), pero esta excepcion no existe en la version actual instalada (v7.43)

La pregunta que me queda es ¿ Por que no se lanza el error de que tal excepcion no existe como deberia se tipico error php ? seria cosa de investigar